# cifs Required Key Not Available

Tags: active-directory, mount, cifs, centos7, likewise-open

I have joined to a zentyal domain (AD Domain) using PowerBroker IS and I want it to mount my remote home directories when a remote user logs in.
this is the config for PBIS:

```
AllowDeleteTo ""
AllowReadTo ""
AllowWriteTo ""
MaxDiskUsage 104857600
MaxEventLifespan 90
MaxNumEvents 100000
DomainSeparator "\\"
SpaceReplacement "^"
EnableEventlog false
Providers "ActiveDirectory"
DisplayMotd false
PAMLogLevel "error"
UserNotAllowedError "Access denied"
AssumeDefaultDomain true
CreateHomeDir true
CreateK5Login true
SyncSystemTime true
TrimUserMembership true
LdapSignAndSeal false
LogADNetworkConnectionEvents true
NssEnumerationEnabled true
NssGroupMembersQueryCacheOnly true
NssUserMembershipQueryCacheOnly false
RefreshUserCredentials true
CacheEntryExpiry 14400
DomainManagerCheckDomainOnlineInterval 300
DomainManagerUnknownDomainCacheTimeout 3600
MachinePasswordLifespan 2592000
MemoryCacheSizeCap 0
HomeDirPrefix "/home"
HomeDirTemplate "%H/%U"
RemoteHomeDirTemplate "%H/%U"
HomeDirUmask "022"
LoginShellTemplate "/bin/bash"
SkeletonDirs "/etc/skel"
UserDomainPrefix "mosek.zentyal"
DomainManagerIgnoreAllTrusts false
DomainManagerIncludeTrustsList
DomainManagerExcludeTrustsList
RequireMembershipOf
Local_AcceptNTLMv1 true
Local_HomeDirTemplate "%H/%U"
Local_HomeDirUmask "022"
Local_LoginShellTemplate "/bin/sh"
Local_SkeletonDirs "/etc/skel"
UserMonitorCheckInterval 1800
LsassAutostart true
EventlogAutostart true
```

As i understand it, so long RemoteHomeDirTemplate is set, it should mount, but the problem is, that it doesn't.

So I thought of trying to find a user, and see how it's home dir path is shown, if it is at all:

```
# /opt/pbis/bin/find-objects --user tomas
User object [1 of 1] (S-1-5-21-755094111-53741902-1678977104-1108)
============
Enabled: yes
Distinguished name: CN=Tomas Nielsen,CN=Users,DC=mosek,DC=zentyal
SAM account name: tomas
NetBIOS domain name: MOSEK
UPN: tomas@MOSEK.ZENTYAL
Display Name: Tomas Nielsen
Alias: <null>
UNIX name: MOSEK\tomas
GECOS: Tomas Nielsen
Shell: /bin/bash
Home directory: /home/tomas
Windows home directory: \\nyborg.MOSEK.ZENTYAL\tomas
Local windows home directory: /home/tomas
UID: 1588593748
Primary group SID: S-1-5-21-755094111-53741902-1678977104-513
Primary GID: 1588593153
Password expired: no
Password never expires: no
Change password on next logon: no
User can change password: yes
Account disabled: no
Account expired: no
Account locked: no
```

so It has a home dir path, both for unix and windows, so I don't see what could be the problem.

In my `/var/log/messages` I found some errors:

```
Dec  4 12:55:30 winbind lsass: [lsass] Failed mount of //nyborg.MOSEK.ZENTYAL/tomas on /home/tomas with data sec=krb5i,user=tomas@MOSEK.ZENTYAL,uid=1588593748,gid=1588593153,cruid=1588593748,ip=172.16.0.5, error 40188 (errno 126)
Dec  4 12:55:30 winbind lsass: [lsass] Failed mount of //nyborg.MOSEK.ZENTYAL/tomas on /home/tomas, error 3690996880 (errno 40188)
Dec  4 12:55:30 winbind lsass: [lsass] Failed to mount directory for user (tomas), actual error 40188
Dec  4 12:55:30 winbind lsass: [lsass] Failed to open session for user (name = 'tomas') -> error = 40188, symbol = LW_ERROR_UNKNOWN, client pid = 2329
Dec  4 12:55:30 winbind kernel: CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -126
Dec  4 12:55:30 winbind kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -126
```

I tried running the command manually and got the correct error message to error 126:

```
#mount -t cifs -o sec=krb5i,user=tomas@MOSEK.ZENTYAL,uid=1588593748,gid=1588592152,cruid=1588593748,ip=172.16.0.5 //nyborg.MOSEK.ZENTYAL/tomas /home/tomas
mount error(126): Required key not available
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I checked that I have a krb ticket:

```
#klist
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:0:0
Default principal: tomas@MOSEK.ZENTYAL

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
12/09/2014 12:20:36  12/09/2014 22:20:36  krbtgt/MOSEK.ZENTYAL@MOSEK.ZENTYAL
    renew until 12/16/2014 12:20:33
```

Okay I found out that if I made a ticket with the user, I could mount it manually.
If I go in and `kinit tomas@MOSEK.ZENTYAL` while on the tomas user, PBIS gets the cifs `error 16` instead

so what could course this problem?

EDIT:

I tried installing the new version of pbis(PBIS Open 8.2.1), and the error I get is different now:

```
[root@centosy tomas]# tail /var/log/messages 
Jan 22 12:43:36 centosy lsass: [lsass] Failed mount of //nyborg.MOSEK.ZENTYAL/tomas on /home/tomas with data sec=krb5i,user=tomas@MOSEK.ZENTYAL,uid=1588593748,gid=1588593153,cruid=1588593748,ip=172.16.0.5, error 40158 (errno 13)
Jan 22 12:43:36 centosy lsass: [lsass] Failed mount of //nyborg.MOSEK.ZENTYAL/tomas on /home/tomas, error 1879066032 (errno 40158)
Jan 22 12:43:36 centosy lsass: [lsass] Failed to mount directory for user (tomas), actual error 40158
Jan 22 12:43:36 centosy lsass: [lsass] Failed to open session for user (name = 'tomas') -> error = 40158, symbol = LW_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, client pid = 2353
Jan 22 12:43:36 centosy lsass: [lsass] Failed mount of //nyborg.MOSEK.ZENTYAL/tomas on /home/tomas with data sec=krb5,user=tomas@MOSEK.ZENTYAL,uid=1588593748,gid=1588593153,cruid=1588593748,ip=172.16.0.5, error 40158 (errno 13)
Jan 22 12:43:36 centosy lsass: [lsass] Failed mount of //nyborg.MOSEK.ZENTYAL/tomas on /home/tomas with data sec=krb5i,user=tomas@MOSEK.ZENTYAL,uid=1588593748,gid=1588593153,cruid=1588593748,ip=172.16.0.5, error 40158 (errno 13)
Jan 22 12:43:36 centosy lsass: [lsass] Failed mount of //nyborg.MOSEK.ZENTYAL/tomas on /home/tomas, error 1879066032 (errno 40158)
Jan 22 12:43:36 centosy lsass: [lsass] Failed to mount directory for user (tomas), actual error 40158
Jan 22 12:43:36 centosy lsass: [lsass] Failed to open session for user (name = 'tomas') -> error = 40158, symbol = LW_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, client pid = 2353
Jan 22 12:44:11 centosy su: (to root) tomas on pts/0
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the answer to your problem, see my own question here:

[Powerbroker Open : Cannot automount CIFS share, where is the kerberos ticket?](https://serverfault.com/questions/720840/powerbroker-open-cannot-automount-cifs-share-where-is-the-kerberos-ticket)

CentOS 7 uses systemd and the PBIS service is configured to use private "tmp" folders. Unfortunately this leads to a Kerberos ticket created in the wrong directory (it is generated in /tmp/systemd-private-xxx instead of /tmp). I edited the service configuration `lwsmd.service` and set `PrivateTmp=no`. Now everything works...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message yesterday; in my case, it was a matter of addressing the server (which has multiple names in DNS) by the DNS same it is known as to the AD server.

Comment: You can also add additional service principal names (SPNs) for that machine.